The connectgatt method will time out. After retrying a few times, it will occasionally connect again
In mid-July, many users reported this problem in the app, but no Bluetooth-related code has been modified recently. Most of the users who reported this use Android 14 phones. In the project, compilesdkversion = 34, targetsdkversion = 33. Not sure if it is related to Google's recent requirement for app targetsdkversion to be upgraded.
Yesterday I strengthened the check of bluetooth_scan permissions and increased targetsdkversion=34. I hope the user side can return to normal.

Everything about this question confuses me

I found the reason. My colleague set the autoconnect parameter of the connectgatt method to true. This caused the device to connect when it was available.
